# Compiling NDKr12b - running into issues trying to compile Matrix.h from Eigen library

Tags: android, c++, eigen

I am importing the `matrix.h` file into my android project..  Here are the errors that pop-up. How do I resolve these errors?

```
 /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:20:8: error: 'traits' is not a class template
   struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
          ^
  /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:20:15: error: 'Matrix' was not declared in this scope
   struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
                 ^
  /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:20:75: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
   struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
                                                                             ^
  In file included from /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Regions.h:21:0,
                   from /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/IMD.h:8,
                   from /xrffunk/src/xrffunk.cpp:28:
  /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:181:27: error: expected template-name before '<' token
     : public PlainObjectBase<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
                             ^
  /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:181:27: error: expected '{' before '<' token
  /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:181:27: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
  /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:430:32: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 6)
   typedef Matrix<Type, Size, Size> Matrix##SizeSuffix##TypeSuffix;  \
                                  ^
  /xrffunk/src/deconvolution/SumPeaks/Matrix.h:443:1: note: in expansion of macro 'EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS'
   EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 2, 2) \
   ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly include `Eigen/src/CoreMatrix.h` which is an internal file. You have to include `Eigen/Core` that requires all files within `Eigen/src/Core`.